# Cant check if CGPoint is not equal CGPointZero

Tags: ios, if-statement, cgpoint

I have a `CGPoint` declared in a `UIView` class, in my `viewController` I try to check if that `CGPoint` is not equal to `CGPointZero`, but I get this error:`Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') and 'CGPoint')`

This is the if-statement:

```
if (joystick.velocity != CGPointZero)
```

The error points to the != and I dont know why it gives me an error.

`joystick` is the `UIView` class, `CGPoint velocity` is declared like this:

`@property(nonatomic) CGPoint velocity;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(joystick.velocity, CGPointZero))
```

Explanation: A CGPoint is actually a struct. The binary operand ("==" or "!=") it's only used to compare primitive values, usually useful to compare pointers, which in fact are integers representing a memory position.

As you have a struct, and not a reference to something, you would have to compare each value inside your struct, but fortunately apple already implemented a macro that performs this for you in the case of CGPoint.

If you are curious, you can command-click the macro above and see the implementation:

```
__CGPointEqualToPoint(CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2)
{
  return point1.x == point2.x && point1.y == point2.y;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to this answer :)

Comment: Gonna try this now it was something like this i thought it would be, like the isEqualToString method.